# Overload operator () with templates

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm doing a homework that needs to be done using templates: it's a matrix class.

One of tells me to overload the `operator ()(int r, int c);`, so I can access my data using `obj(a, b);` or change it with `obj(a, b)=100;`.

The template for my class is `template<class T, int C, int R>;`
Then I created inside my class in the public scope a:

```
T& operator()(int r, int c);//LINE 16
```

The implementation is simple.

I tried in 2 ways:

```
template <class T>
T& Matrix::operator()(int r, int c){
    return matrixData[r][c];
}

template <class T, int C, int R>
T& Matrix::operator()(int r, int c){ 
    return matrixData[r][c];
}
```

In the last one I get the error telling me:

```
16: Error: expected type-specifier before '(' token
```

the line 16 is above with a commentary error:

```
no 'T& Matrix<T, C, R>::operator()(int, int)' member function declared in class 'Matrix<T, C, R>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The class is `template<class T, int C, int R> class Matrix {...}`:

The following works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int R, int C>
class Matrix {
  T data[R][C];
public:
  T& operator()(int r, int c);
};

template <typename T, int R, int C>
T& Matrix<T, R, C>::operator()(int r, int c) {
  return data[r][c];
}

int main() {
  Matrix<int, 3, 4> m;
  m(0, 1) = 42;
  std::cout << m(0, 1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It says:
wrong number of parameters.
I created some friend operators and they worked well, but now i cant solve that.

Comment: @demonofnight: The code in my (edited) answer compiles fine for me.

Comment: If i keeps only the class T it dont work, it seems i need to put the <class T, int R, int C>.
It tells me that the number of arguments should be 3 and not 1.
The class is template<class T, int C, int R> class Matrix{...}
If i fix that with all the 3 parameters, my main tells me that i have a undefined referece to matrix<int, 100, 100>::operator()(int, int)

Comment: Thanks, the problem now is, the compiler tells me that i have a undefined reference to matrix<int, 100, 100>::operator()(int, int), so i'm looking if its because of the implementation or if i did something wrong/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you're missing the type on `Matrix`:

```
template <class T>
T& Matrix<T>::operator()(int r, int c){
    return matrixData[r][c];
}

template <class T, int C, int R>
T& Matrix<T>::operator()(int r, int c){ 
    return matrixData[r][c];
}
```